# Remix Unit Testing: Fail message is giving wrong name of the test file

Tags: remix, remix-tests

I am trying to do unit testing using Remix using the tutorial at [Simple Contract at Medium](https://medium.com/remix-ide/simple-contract-with-remix-7285af713d99), but it is giving me a FAIL message with “browser/tests/4_Ballot_test.sol) file highlighted with blue background. On the other hand , I am using the file browser/tests/SimpleStorage_test.sol.

I have attached the image.

Somebody please guide me.

Zulfi.
[image: Wrong file name in Remix Unit Testing]